# Godot: Display EditorInspector on another panel with plugins?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm attempting to make a plugin to make loading a dictionary or resources easier. There are many aspects I'm not even sure will work, and I can't seem to find an answer to elsewhere, so I'll ask here.

1. Is it possible to, when clicking on a custom resource/custom property, to open a specific tab on the bottom panel (where output, debugger, etc. are)? In this case, my custom Dictionary Loader tab.
2. Since EditorInspector inherits from ScrollContainer, is it possible to make my own node of it, and place it within a custom ui? I understand I can't access it from the editor, but how about gdscript? I tried `EditorInspector.new()` and adding it as a child, but it doesn't display in the scene hierarchy or visually so I can't tell if it works. Can I/should I use EditorInspectorPlugin?
3. If 2 is possible, can I also assign it the node/resource I want to see the properties of? Nothing in the class's documentation shows how it populates its ui with the EditorProperties.

[image: My custom editor panel]
The 2nd column is an itemlist of dictionary keys. Clicking one would bring up an EditorInspector equivalent in the 3rd column area for its resource value. Before I found the EditorInspector class in the documentation, I was considering using `_get_property_list()` and populating the 3rd column with custom ui for each property. But if a class already exists to do that, why can't I use a copy of it? I just don't know how to set it up, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a inspector plugin that adds a control that will show a panel...

---

Start by creating an plugin from the editor (Project -> Project settings -> Plugins -> Create -> Fill the form and click Create). It will generate the plugin in the addons folder of your project (there should be a script that extends `EditorPlugin`).

---

Now add a script that extends `EditorInspectorPlugin`. From your plugin script you can load it, instance it, and add it with `add_inspector_plugin` and remove it with `remove_inspector_plugin`. *You want to add it on `_enter_tree` and remove it on `_exit_tree`.*

---

In the script that extends `EditorInspectorPlugin`, override the `can_handle` function. Godot will call it when an object is shown in the inspector, and your script must return `true` or `false` depending if it can handle said object. For example, I want to handle `Camera`, I would write this:

```
func can_handle(object:Object) -> bool:
    return object is Camera
```

You probably want to simply return `true` since your inspector plugin is not based on the type of object, but the properties it has.

---

Then there are some other methods you can override. In particular, I believe you want `parse_property`, which looks like this:

```
func parse_property(object: Object, type: int, path: String, hint: int, hint_text: String, usage: int) -> bool:
    return false
```

The code you want to add there must do these things:

- Check if it is a property you can handle.

  Since you care about the type, you want to read it, which you can do calling `get` on the `object` and passing the `path`. And then check if what you got is a `Dictionary`:

  ```
  if object.get(path) is Dictionary:
      pass
  ```
- If it is a property you can handle, add a `Control` using `add_custom_control`.

  You can create a `Control` scene, instance it, and pass it to `add_custom_control`.
- Return `true` if you did all that. Otherwise return `false`.

---

So, you probably will add a button that must open a panel. So you need a panel... We will figure out how to connect them soon…

Presumably you already have the scene you want to show in the panel. You can add it from your plugin script with `add_control_to_bottom_panel`, and remove it with `remove_control_from_bottom_panel`.

You also want to be able to call a method on that scene that takes either a reference to the object being edited and the property path, or a reference to the dictionary itself directly. Whichever is more convenient for you. You will also need to be able to clear said reference.

On a similar note, you need to handle visibility of said panel. So it hides when there is nothing to edit.

---

Alright, on the script that extends `EditorInspectorPlugin` you can add a signal to notify about what to show on the panel. And on the plugin script you can handle it, and have it call the method on the panel scene.

Furthermore, you can override `parse_begin`... It is intended to add controls at the start of the inspector, but you can use it to emit the signal to notify to show nothing on the panel because the user is now inspecting a different object.

So when the user clicks the button (or interacts with whatever control) you added to the inspector, you want to emit the same signal too. So you connect a signal from that button (or whatever control) to a method that emits your signal.

*And so when the user interacts, it emits a signals that the script that extends `EditorInspectorPlugin` handles by emitting a signal that the plugin script handles by telling the panel what to show.*

*Yes, you can cut some steps here: have the plugin script give a reference to the panel to the script that extends `EditorInspectorPlugin` so it can call it directly. I'll leave it to you if you want to couple them like that.*

*You may also use a `parse_begin` and `parse_end`, plus keeping track of how many controls you added in `parse_property` (in `parse_begin` you reset the count, in `parse_property` you increment the count, in `parse_end` you check). To find out if an object has no properties you handle, or just for debugging.*

Comment: So following your instructions, I was able to connect most things how i wanted. A checkbox appears in the inspector next to all dictionaries asking if its a Resource Dictionary, and if true opens the bottom panel with my custom UI, and gives it a reference to the dictionary so it can populate the keys column.
_**What i'm still unsure how to do**_: I don't know how to show specific resources in the 3rd column after clicking their respective key. Do I use the same EditorInspectorPlugin, or a new one? I'm unsure how to return godot's default property ui to my custom bottom panel ui.

Comment: As if I had clicked a .tres file in the FileSystem and the resource shows up in the inspector panel, how do I make it so when I click something in my custom bottom panel ui, I can bring up that resource and its properties within my custom ui?

Comment: @DemonBismuth How to show Godot's default ui is something I haven't solved. As far as I know there is no API readily available to get Godot's inspector ui for something… There could be a way to do it, I don't know (what I have seen is addon authors going into the trouble of recreating the inspector ui with custom scenes to some degree of success). You can try using `edit_resource` from the plugin script, I believe it would open the resource in the inspector.