# how to disable tool mode entry box widget?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to lock an entry widget in tool mode like this:

```
tool
extends Node

export(bool) var locked=false
export(String) var entry="" setget set_entry

func set_entry(new_val):
    if!(locked):
        entry=new_val
```

In theory, this should prevent any changes made to the entry widget
as It would rapidly change back to the previous value hence giving the illusion of being disabled

but in reality, you can type freely and after you select another node and then reselect the original node then the value returns to what it was before locking

How do I disable it completely? (perhaps using `_set()`?)

**Edit**

This is the problem I'm facing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To disable it completely, I think you need an [Inspector Plugin](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/inspector_plugins.html) (I talked a little about creating one [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73639830/402022)). You could make one that handles the property you are interested in and displays its value, but does not allow to edit it, or only allows to edit it conditionally.

However, for a quick and dirty approach you can do is tell the inspector that the properties changed:

```
func set_entry(new_val):
    if!(locked):
        entry=new_val

    property_list_changed_notify()
```

This will cause the inspector to re-read the values of the properties. *It can be a bit annoying, depending on the case. By the way, it seems to be ignored in sub-resources, which I find frustrating.*

*By the way, Godot 4 has `PROPERTY_USAGE_READ_ONLY`.*

---

**Addendum**: We can be a little more aggressive than `property_list_changed_notify`, by using `EditorInterface.inspect_object` (we can get an instance of `EditorInterface` from an instance of `EditorPlugin`). Godot would reload the inspector (which also results in losing the keyboard focus).

Comment: I tried `property_list_changed_notify()` but makes no change and still gives the same problem (check the edit) and isn't making an inspector plugin  a bit overkill for something so simple?